# Error getting Home Graph: TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: google-smart-home

I was trying to use Home Graph Viewer Tools, entered my project-id (100% right id) but they returned the error:

```
Error getting Home Graph: TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

Please help!
Thanks!

[Error detail image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLo43.png)

I was trying to re-enter the project-id but nothing changed

Comment: Hi! Please edit your question properly so it is easier and more straightforward for future helper users! Specially code as code, and error details also as code!

Answer (score 0):

There are certain trait attributes that come as an array format, such as [availableThermostatModes](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/traits/temperaturesetting) that you provide as a list of values in your Sync response. If we get a blank list this might lead to this error as blank list of values is not iterable. Please double check what you are sending in Sync Response.

Similarly, when you provide states for devices for some trait attributes you provide multiple values (ex. [ColorSetting](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/traits/colorsetting): RGB or HSV ) For these state values HomeGraph Viewer will be traversing an array which should not be empty/undefined.
For these, double check the state values you are sending to us as a part of [ReportState](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/integration/report-state).